# c# What does this line mean?

Tags: c#, return-value, null-coalescing-operator

Could anybody explain the following code `return total ?? decimal.Zero` please?

```
public decimal GetTotal()
{
    // Part Price * Count of parts sum all totals to get basket total
    decimal? total = (from basketItems in db.Baskets
                      where basketItems.BasketId == ShoppingBasketId
                      select (int?)basketItems.Qty * basketItems.Part.Price).Sum();
    return total ?? decimal.Zero;
}
```

Does it mean the following?

```
    if (total !=null) return total;
    else return 0;
```

Comment: So based on about 10 responses, i guess it's called the "null-coalescing operator" then??? :p

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, that's what it means. It's called the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

It's just a syntax shortcut. However, it can be more efficient because the value being read is only evaluated once. (Note that there can also be a functional difference in cases where evaluating the value twice has side effects.)

Comment: In addition to this, the specific code example is equivilent to `return total.GetValueOrDefault(decimal.Zero)` or simply `return total.GetValueOrDefault()` because decimal defaults to zero anyway.

Answer (score 6):

The `??` in C# is called the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).  It's *roughly* equivalent to the following code

```
if (total != null) {
  return total.Value;
} else {
  return Decimal.Zero;
}
```

The one key difference between the above `if` statement expansion and the `??` operator is how side effects are processed.  In the `??` example the side effects of getting the value `total` only happen once but in the `if` statement they happen twice.

In this case it doesn't matter because `total` is a local hence there are no side effects.  But this can be a factor if say it's a side effecting property or method call.

```
// Here SomeOperation happens twice in the non-null case 
if (SomeOperation() != null) {
  return SomeOperation().Value;
} else { 
  return Decimal.Zero;
}

// vs. this where SomeOperation only happens once
return SomeOperation() ?? Decimal.Zero;
```

Comment: To be more precise, you could evaluate the value once in your equivalent code block, i.e. `tmp = SomeOperation(); if (tmp != null) { return tmp.Value; } else { return Decimal.Zero; }`

Answer (score 4):

It's the null coalescing operator.

Effectively, it's like rewriting the code this way:

```
 return (total != null) ? total.Value : decimal.Zero;
```

Comment: No, it's like rewriting the code `return (total != null) ? total.Value : decimal.Zero;`

Comment: My mistake, I didnt notice it was a `decimal?`. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You nailed it. It's called the null-coalescing operator. Check it out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It returns the first non-null expression (the first expression being `total`, and the second expression being `decimal.Zero`)

So if `total` is null, `decimal.Zero` will be returned.